# How to change ownership of folder inside the container after build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this service in my `docker-compose.yml`

php-fpm:
container_name: php_app
restart: always
build:
context: .
dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
volumes:
- ./src:/var/www/html

that take everything of the host folder `src` and add to `/var/www/html`:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN apk add icu-dev

COPY docker/php-fpm/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
RUN npm install

COPY src src/

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

accessing the container using `sudo docker exec -it php_app sh`  and executing `ls -la` I have:

drwxrwxr-x    6 1001     1001          4096 May 12 15:54 writable

which must be owned by `www-data`, how can I set the ownership automatically when the builds complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create the www-data user in the dockerfile eg

```
RUN addgroup -g 1000 www-data && adduser -G www-data -g www-data -s /bin/sh -D www-data

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www-data && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```